# How to put array into CSV file and echo it out into an href?

Tags: php, arrays, file, csv

I want to put an array into a csv file, and echo it out in a href link, that file, to download it when I press on that link. How can I do that?

I have this code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
$data = array(
        'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
        '123,456,789',
        '"aaa","bbb"'
);

$fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
foreach ( $data as $line ) {
    $val = explode(",", $line);
    fputcsv($fp, $val);
}
fclose($fp);
```

If I use this, It will directly download me a csv file that contains my array. How can I put this into a href link? Thanks.

Comment: You must put a link to this script in href attribute. You cannot put contents of the file there.

Comment: I want to put a href link to download my csv file.

Comment: Then what stops you? You should know the script address, no?

Comment: That's my question. what is that address? If i use my code, it will directly download my csv file because i got my second header(). How can i put that header() into <a href=""/> ?

Comment: `fopen(fileNameHere, 'w')`

Comment: Is 'php://output' accessible by the web server? If so, what is the path to 'output' with respect to the web root?

Comment: Kinda confuse... Can't put fopen into my href, like: <a href="?php fopen()?">...</a>

Comment: put this code into file with name "download.php" and then on another page you can provide link `<a href="download.php">download</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You could use GET parameter to decide whether to produce the file contents, like you do now, or produce the HTML with a link to the same page, but with the additional GET parameter.

Something like the following:

```
if (isset($_GET('download')) {
    // your original code:
    header('Content-Type: application/excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="sample.csv"');
    $data = array(
            'aaa,bbb,ccc,dddd',
            '123,456,789',
            '"aaa","bbb"'
    );

    $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
    foreach ( $data as $line ) {
        $val = explode(",", $line);
        fputcsv($fp, $val);
    }
    fclose($fp);
} else {
    // get current page URL and append the download parameter
    $href = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?download=1";
    // output the HTML hyperlink, which will lead to the above `if` code
?>
    <a href="<?=$href?>">download CSV</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

The above code assumes that your "non-download" request does not have any URL arguments, otherwise you need to add the *download* argument with an ampersand. You should also manage the hash character, if you use it in your URL.